# Why can't I see my console logs in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, console, google-chrome-devtools

I would like to view the details of the three logged objects. Instead of rendering like I expect it renders a blue circle with the number of log entries. if I just use the console and log something it works as I expect.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the log only groups primitive values, (e.g. string, number, etc). Is it possible the log statement, producing the grouped output, is logging the string "object" three times? Note the word object is capitalized when referring to `{tacos: "tacos"}`, but is not capitalized in the grouped output, this is evidence the grouped output is a primitive string, not a complex object.

Comment: I feel so dumb about this but I had console.log(typeof(obj)). (sigh)